# Pass command line arguments with docker exec as a tag

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I have a main.java function that uses command like arguments to run processes specific to the input. I am now running the java project through a docker container. I would need the command be similar to

```
docker exec -it container_id -argument1
```

How would I specify in dockerfile what "-argument1" is and to send it to the main.java for execution?

Comment: How does “docker exec” come into it?  It bypasses the usual Docker command line setup.

Comment: What do you mean by `I have a main.java function that uses command like arguments to run processes specific to the input`? `java com.tst.Main argument1` is your command or something else?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to pass your arguments as environment variables. Ex:
`docker exec -it <container_id> -e "FOO=BAR" <command>`

Then use `System.getenv("FOO");` to get the value.